# Getting my calculator to take a new number after the equal button is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have been at this for a while now and still cannot get my calculator to do one final thing.

I got it thanks!

After I push the equal button or Tan, Sin, Cos or Mod buttons I want my calculator to take a new number. Basically as if nothing was in the textbox even though the answer is still there. Currently, all the numbers stay and the new number is added to the end. I do not want this to happen.

After the calculation, if I push a number button I want it to clear the screen and add the new number fresh. Below is my code that I have so far.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Double FirstNumber;
    string mathOperator = "";

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        mathOperator = "+";

        DisplayTextBox.Text = "";
        DisplayTextBox.Focus();

    }
    private void EqualButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Double SecondNumber;
        SecondNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);

        switch (mathOperator)
        {
            case "+":
                DisplayTextBox.Text = (FirstNumber + SecondNumber).ToString();
                break;
            case "-":
                DisplayTextBox.Text = (FirstNumber - SecondNumber).ToString();
                break;
            case "*":
                DisplayTextBox.Text = (FirstNumber * SecondNumber).ToString();
                break;
            case "/":
                DisplayTextBox.Text = (FirstNumber / SecondNumber).ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        FirstNumber *= -1;
        DisplayTextBox.Text = FirstNumber.ToString();

    }

    private void ButtonMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        mathOperator = "-";

        DisplayTextBox.Text = "";
        DisplayTextBox.Focus();

    }

    private void ButtonMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        mathOperator = "*";

        DisplayTextBox.Text = "";
        DisplayTextBox.Focus();

    }

    private void ButtonDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        mathOperator = "/";

        DisplayTextBox.Text = "";
        DisplayTextBox.Focus();

    }

    private void ButtonMod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        DisplayTextBox.Text = Math.Tan(FirstNumber).ToString();

    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "1";
    }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "2";
    }

    private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "3";
    }

    private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "4";
    }

    private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "5";
    }

    private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "6";
    }

    private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "7";
    }

    private void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "8";
    }

    private void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "9";
    }

    private void ButtonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = "";
        mathOperator = "";
    }

    private void ButtonOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void ButtonTan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        DisplayTextBox.Text = Math.Tan(FirstNumber).ToString();
    }

    private void ButtonSin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        DisplayTextBox.Text = Math.Sin(FirstNumber).ToString();

    }

    private void ButtonCos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);
        DisplayTextBox.Text = Math.Cos(FirstNumber).ToString();

    }

    private void Button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DisplayTextBox.Text.Length >= 1)
        {
            DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "0";
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void DecimalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DisplayTextBox.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide only small piece of code which reproduces your problem. I wonder if anybody will read this code dump till the end

Comment: Why don't you implement a C or CC button (or both) ?

Comment: @bhs OP's problem is when he types `1+2` he gets `12` on display instead of `2`, because `1` is not removed, and it should be.

Comment: ah - good spot. with you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Boolean variable to your class that represents a flag of whether or not an operation has  just completed or not, like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Double FirstNumber;
    string mathOperator = "";
    bool operationJustCompleted = false;
```

Initially, the value will be `false`, because nothing has happened when the calculator is first created.

Now, at the end of the equal button event handler, set the flag to true, like this:

```
private void EqualButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Logic for calculation

    operationJustCompleted = true;
}
```

Finally, in the event handlers for the number buttons, check to see if the `operationJustCompleted` flag is true, if so then clear the text and reset the operation just completed flag back to `false`; like this:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(operationJustCompleted)
    {
        DisplayTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
        operationJustCompleted = false;
    }
    DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a state variable to your class. When true, and a number is selected, clear the display and set it false before writing the number.

When "=" is clicked, set it true.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a brief review, seems like you need to introduce a variable that will keep track of the calculator’s state, and then when “equal” button is pressed, set the state to calculated value.  Then, in the numeric buttons (0-9) you need to check the state variable and either append to or replace the display text.

Answer (score 0):

Create this global variable...

```
private bool equationComplete = false;
```

Add this to the end of the Equals button...

```
equationComplete = true;
```

Add this to the beginning of each number button click...

```
if (equationComplete) DisplayTextBox.Text = "";
```

Add this to the end of each number button click event handler...

```
equationComplete = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like David Arno says, something like this:

```
    private void EqualButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearDisplayBeforeNextTextEntry = true;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // New code
        ClearText();
        // Old code
        DisplayTextBox.Text = DisplayTextBox.Text + "1";
    }

    // Same for all other number buttons as above

    private void ClearText()
    {
        if (ClearDisplayBeforeNextTextEntry)
        {
            DisplayTextBox.Text = "";
            ClearDisplayBeforeNextTextEntry = false;
        }
    }
```